# Why isn't FullCalendar showing here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to get a simple, empty calendar to show up on a page. I have followed the documentation at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/ and the below code seems ok so should be showing a calendar.

Am I doing something wrong here?

### Updated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Calendar</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.print.css">

    <script src="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
        })

    });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Calendar</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Bookings <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>

      <!-- Main component to show the calendar-->
      <div id="calendar"></div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMUzA.png

Comment: `Am I doing something wrong here?` Yeah, you didn't create us a fiddle ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `fullCalendar()` plugin on the element with **id** #calendar, while you have created a DOM element with the **class** .calendar.

So either change this line:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

to

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar()
```

**OR** change this line:

```
<div class="calendar"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I would opt for using id instead of class, unless you plan on having multiple calendars on this page.

Comment: Thanks. I changed `class` to `id` but also I had to remove the JavaScript at the bottom. Why is that? I need the Bootstrap JavaScript! :-/

Comment: Dunno, who told you that? I do see you are including jquery twice (once from the fullcalendar plugin, once for the bootstrap included version), that could cause problems. I'd move the fullcalendar js to the bottom as well, AFTER the jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: Doesn't each version of Bootstrap require a specific jQuery version? What should I do if Bootstrap requires one version and FullCalendar another, include both?

Comment: no not really. They all have minimum requirements, but (almost) all new versions of jquery are backwards compatible with former versions. So basically it's safe to just include the highest version of the two. Exceptions are jQuery version 1.9.x which has a somewhat different api then former versions, and version 2.x which doesn't support IE8 and below (but you don't want that anyway...)